# Percentage growth between values in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, percentage

Let's say that I have a df like below:

```
x     name
12    q
1     q
3     q
383   z
31    z
21    z
 68   r
 32   r
 2    r
```

I need to count the percentage growth between first and last value for each of name, so result should be like this

```
x     name
300%   q
1723%  z
20%    r
```

I tried to use first group by name but now I can't move forward. Do you have any ideas how to fix it ?

Thanks All for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) functions and then use [`pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
df = (df.groupby('name')['x']
       .agg([('a','last'),('x','first')])
       .pct_change(axis=1)['x']
       .mul(100)
       .reset_index())
print (df)
  name            x
0    q   300.000000
1    r  3300.000000
2    z  1723.809524
```

Another solution:

```
a = df.drop_duplicates('name', keep='last').set_index('name')['x']
b = df.drop_duplicates('name').set_index('name')['x']

df = b.sub(a).div(a).mul(100).round(2).reset_index()
print (df)
  name        x
0    q   300.00
1    z  1723.81
2    r  3300.00
```

Comment: and maybe one more thing, do you know how to round values to have no decimal points ?

Comment: Sure, only add `.round(2)` after `mul(100)` :)